# .vtt file formats be hosted on SFMC - Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, content-builder

Can .vtt file formats be hosted on SFMC? We are facing an issue hosting this file type. We want to add this to our Interactive CloudPage

Answer (score 2):

No.

List of supported file types can be found [**here**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_supported_file_types.htm&type=5).